# Getting Bad Request when requesting JWT in web API from Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, asp.net-web-api2

So I made a web API that authenticates with JSON Web Tokens, however, I haven't been able to authenticate using the HttpClient from my xamarin forms application. The odd thing is that I can connect without any problem on a console application that I made for testing, and both the console application and the xamarin forms app use almost exactly the same code.

The code in the console app is like this:

```
public static async Task<AutenticacionModel> PostCredentialsAsync(string UserName, string Password)
{
    HttpClient cliente = new HttpClient();
    cliente.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://172.25.1.53:9891");
    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    string _result = String.Empty;
    try
    {
        string Path = cliente.BaseAddress + "oauth/secreto";
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, Path);
        string autenticacion = "username=" + UserName + "&password=" + Password + "&grant_type=password";
        request.Content = new StringContent(autenticacion, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        response = await cliente.SendAsync(request);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        _result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // something to do
    }
    return response.Content != null ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AutenticacionModel>(_result) : new AutenticacionModel();
}
```

And the code in the Xamarin Forms:

```
public async Task<AutenticacionDTO> GetUsuario(string email, string clave)
{
    string JSONAutenticacion;
    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();

    try
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(GlobalSetting.UrlWebApi);
        string Path = client.BaseAddress + "oauth/secreto";
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, Path);
        string autenticacion = "username=" + email + "&password=" + clave + "&grant_type=password";
        request.Content = new StringContent(autenticacion, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        JSONAutenticacion = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string sss = ex.ToString();
        return null;
    }
    return response.Content != null ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AutenticacionDTO>(JSONAutenticacion) : new AutenticacionDTO();
}
```

When I use postman to connect to the web API that I have hosted in my local IIS, there's no problem, same with the console application. But whenever I try to connect with the Xamarin Forms App I get a 400 Bad Request response.

The code that makes the Jwt work goes like this:

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
    var allowedOrigin = "*";
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { allowedOrigin });
    Seguridad _Seguridad = new fovissste.bll.Seguridad();
    LoginDTO Usuario = _Seguridad.Login(context.UserName, context.Password).FirstOrDefault();

    if (Usuario == null)
    {
        context.SetError("invalid_grant", "Usuario o contraseña incorrectos");
        return;
    }

    ClaimsIdentity oauthIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(new ApplicationUser(context.UserName, "JWT"), new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Publico") });
    var ticket = await Task.Run(() => new AuthenticationTicket(oauthIdentity, null));
    context.Validated(ticket);
}
```

Can anybody help? Is this an issue with Xamarin Forms? I truly require some comments because I honestly can't see what I'm missing. I've read other posts in this site that suggest that it can be an issue of enabling remote requests on IIS or a CORS issue but I think that's handled in this line: `context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { allowedOrigin });`

Comment: Strange, all code seems the same. Try using a tool like Fiddler or Charles to see what is going over the line in each case. That might help figuring out what is going on.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis I had the same idea, but I couldnt configure fiddler to capture my requests, at least I put a filter that indicates "Show only the following hosts" : http://localhost:9891; but the sessions aren't captured in fiddler

Comment: Are you running from an emulator or device? In case of a device you should set the device's proxy to your machine where Fiddler is running. On an emulator it normally should just work unless you're using HTTPS

Comment: @GeraldVersluis I'm running from device. Thank you I'll research how to set the proxy in the Android

Comment: However, it's working now. I don't know exactly what I changed, I simply copied/pasted the code from the console application. Could it have been network related?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://172.25.1.53:9891");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    string autenticacion = "?username=" + email + "&password=" + clave + "&grant_type=password";
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress + "oauth/secreto", new StringContent(autenticacion, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));

    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    string JSONAutenticacion = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

What is the value of `Path` after this line?

```
string Path = client.BaseAddress + "oauth/secreto";
```

Also try to add this line before `using (var client...` :

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

### Edit

Changed

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress + autenticacion, new StringContent(autenticacion));
```

to

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress + "oauth/secreto", new StringContent(autenticacion, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
```

Comment: didn't work. I must send the request as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"